# PHP Express Checkout Response calls my script twice within seconds

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am configuring an application using PHP and PayPals Express Checkout and after I set the Express Checkout Response and the user logs in, when they come back to my return url it seems to load the script twice within a matter of seconds.

I have checked all the business settings in my sandbox account and I have no IPN's set or auto returns set up so am unsure as to why this would be happening. All the variables that are passed back from PayPal are identical except for the correlationID which is different every time including within the set response so I cannot match them together.

This is the script that saves to the database and I would simply do an update rather than an insert on the first call of the script but it happens so quickly they both do inserts.

(I am using paypal-merchant-sdk-php api)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you must have GetExpressCheckoutDetails getting called twice.  Double check your code logic and make sure you're not calling it twice somehow.

PayPal simply redirects to your site, and once that redirect is done they can't redirect again, of course, so they can't hit you twice.

PDT doesn't work with Express Checkout, so that wouldn't be causing it, and IPN doesn't occur until after the payment is complete, so that wouldn't be causing it either.

Again, it sounds like you're calling GECD twice.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. You were right. It turns out that having the html line <link rel="shortcut icon" href=""> in there was causing this issue. It must be something to do with a rewrite or 404 issue that reloads it when it cannot find it.